# Unable to run UFT automation scripts using edge browser

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, hp-uft

We have built our entire project automation suite using UFT 15.0.1.416. We have used Visual studio 2019 to build the automation suite. And there are around 900 test cases we have automated and able to run all of them without any issues in IE 11 browser.
As IE 11 sooner going to retired by Microsoft, we are planning to migrate to Chrome & Edge.

But we are facing issues with Chrome & Edge browsers to run automation scripts.

**Chrome Browser:** we are able to launch the application & run the scripts.

But running scripts on Chrome is very very slow. It is taking couple of minutes even to execute simple script. When we debug, we have noticed that every operation that interacts with web element is taking lot of time. Even getting the properties of web element like Id, Class are also taking time.

We are using chrome version - 91.0.4472.114.

**Edge browser** - we are unable to lunch the application using edge browser. Keep on getting following error.
[image]
**Exception: General Error occurred**
*at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.Communication.CommunicationClient.HandleError(Action`2 onError, Int32 status, IDictionary`2 data)
at HP.LFT.SDK.Core.Communication.CommunicationClient.Send(String messageType, IDictionary`2 data, Action`2 onError)
at HP.LFT.SDK.Web.BrowserFactory.BrowserFactoryInstance.InternalLaunch(Dictionary`2 launchInfo) at HP.LFT.SDK.Web.BrowserFactory.BrowserFactoryInstance.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Launch>b__1() at HP.LFT.SDK.OperationExecutionWrapper.ExecuteWithEventsInternally[T](ITestObject testObject, Object additionalInfo, Func`1 innerAction, MethodBase methodInfo, Boolean reportOnlyOnError, Object[] arguments)
at HP.LFT.SDK.OperationExecutionWrapper.ExecuteWithEvents[T](ITestObject testObject, Object additionalInfo, Func`1 innerAction, MethodBase methodInfo, Boolean reportOnlyOnError, Object[] arguments) at HP.LFT.SDK.OperationExecutionWrapper.ExecuteWithEvents[T1,TR](Func`1 innerAction, Func`2 originalMethod, T1 param1, Boolean reportOnlyOnError, ITestObject testObject, Object additionalInfo)
at HP.LFT.SDK.Web.BrowserFactory.BrowserFactoryInstance.Launch(BrowserType browserType)
at HP.LFT.SDK.Web.BrowserFactory.Launch(BrowserType browserType)*

And Edge extension is already installed.
[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this type of problems ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to latest UFTD 15.0.2 to solve the issue.

Comment: Now I have UFT 15.0.2.686 in my machine. Now I am able to run the scripts in Edge browser. But still scripts are running very very slow in both chrome & edge browsers when compare to IE 11.

Comment: That seems to be normal :\